# How to check for overdispersion in a GAM with negative binomial distribution?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I fit a Generalized Additive Model in the Negative Binomial family using `gam` from the `mgcv` package. I have a data frame containing my dependent variable `y`, an independent variable `x`, a factor `fac` and a random variable `ran`. I fit the following model

`gam1 <- gam(y ~ fac + s(x) + s(ran, bs = 're'), data = dt, family = "nb"`

I have read in Negative Binomial Regression book that it is still possible for the model to be overdisperesed. I have found code to check for overdispersion in `glm` but I am failing to find it for a `gam`. I have also encountered suggestions to just check the QQ plot and standardised residuals vs. predicted residuals, but I can not decide from my plots if the data is still overdisperesed. Therefore, I am looking for an equation that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to check how well the model compares with the observed data (and hence check for overdispersion in the data relative to the conditional distribution implied by the model) is via a rootogram.

I have a [blog post](https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/06/07/rootograms/) showing how to do this for `glm()` models using the *countreg* package, but this works for GAMs too.

The salient parts of the post applied to a GAM version of the model are:

```
library("coenocliner")
library('mgcv')

## parameters for simulating
set.seed(1)
locs <- runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)     # environmental locations
A0 <- 90                                  # maximal abundance
mu <- 3                                   # position on gradient of optima
alpha <- 1.5                              # parameter of beta response
gamma <- 4                                # parameter of beta response
r <- 6                                    # range on gradient species is present
pars <- list(m = mu, r = r, alpha = alpha, gamma = gamma, A0 = A0)
nb.alpha <- 1.5                           # overdispersion parameter 1/theta
zprobs <- 0.3                             # prob(y == 0) in binomial model

## simulate some negative binomial data from this response model
nb   <- coenocline(locs, responseModel = "beta", params = pars,
                   countModel = "negbin",
                   countParams = list(alpha = nb.alpha))
df <- setNames(cbind.data.frame(locs, nb), c("x", "yNegBin"))
```

OK, so we have a sample of data drawn from a negative binomial sampling distribution and we will now fit two models to these data:

1. A Poisson GAM

```r
m_pois <- gam(yNegBin ~ s(x), data = df, family = poisson())
```

2. A negative binomial GAM

```r
m_nb   <- gam(yNegBin ~ s(x), data = df, family = nb())
```

The *countreg* package is not yet on CRAN but it can be installed from R-Forge:

```
install.packages("countreg", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Then load the packages and plot the rootograms:

```
library("countreg")
library("ggplot2")

root_pois <- rootogram(m_pois, style = "hanging", plot = FALSE)
root_nb   <- rootogram(m_nb, style = "hanging", plot = FALSE)
```

Now plot the rootograms for each model:

```
autoplot(root_pois)
autoplot(root_nb)
```

This is what we get (after plotting both using `cowplot::plot_grid()` to arrange the two rootograms on the same plot)

[image]

We can see that the negative binomial model does a bit better here than the Poisson GAM for these data — the bottom of the bars are closer to zero throughout the range of the observed counts.

The *countreg* package has details on how you can add an uncertain band around the zero line as a form of goodness of fit test.

You can also compute the Pearson estimate for the dispersion parameter using the Pearson residuals of each model:

```
r$>  sum(residuals(m_pois, type = "pearson")^2) / df.residual(m_pois)
[1] 28.61546
r$>  sum(residuals(m_nb, type = "pearson")^2) / df.residual(m_nb)
[1] 0.5918471
```

In both cases, these should be 1; we see substantial overdispersion in the Poisson GAM, and some under-dispersion in the Negative Binomial GAM.